# Im trying to make an iphone app similar to find my friends how do i find the location of my friends on the map?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-location

Im trying to make an iphone app like google latitude or find my friends.
I'm able to find my current location but how do i locate my friends?
And also how do i show that location on the map?

Comment: Please refer `Corelocaiton` framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios) to know about getting user current location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

You Must need a web service that stores locations of each devices when the app is running, then from your app send a query to the web-service from there you will find the list of device using the app.

It's not a very elegant solution since the user is always polling the server and the web request can fail more often than you'd want. I heard about socket programming where the user keeps a live connection to the server and when ever the server changes, the user is notified, sounds more like the right approach but also sounds much harder :P

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155753/any-demo-example-multiple-map-annotation-using-plist/12156477#12156477) For Showing Multiple annotation on MAP.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? in another words, Are there any api's available in google maps for IOS ?